# Clarify some things about OAuth2.0 and Node.JS REST API

Tags: node.js, facebook, rest, api, oauth-2.0

I'm currently developping a REST API with NodeJS and Express for a mobile application written with the Ionic framework.

I have a mysql database in which are stored my users.

I want my API to be safe concerning the authentication of my users and their right to access certain routes and ressources of the API.

My user can either login/register with their own credentials or use Facebook to do it.

---

So, this is what i'm doing right now :

- A user register using one of my API's routes
- When he wants to access a protected route, i use passport-http's Basic Strategy for Basic Auth.

I use it like this:

```
router.route('/protected/route')
    .put(auth.isAuthenticated, controller.someMethod);
```

The auth.isAuthenticated looks like this :

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
  function(username, password, callback) {
    Account.findByEmailAndPassword(username, password, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { callback(err) };
      if (!user) { return callback(null, false); }
      return callback(null, user);
    });
  }
));

exports.isAuthenticated = passport.authenticate('basic', { session : false });
```

- Then, in `controller.someMethod()`, i get my user object in `req.user`. I have a field in my DB that is `type`, i can check what's the type of the user and continue my request or not.

---

Now, using Facebook:

- The client uses Facebook's Login button, authorize my app to access it's data, and then gets an access_token. It is send to my API via an HTTP request.
- The API gets the token, and then start calling the Facebook Graph API to ask information about the user such as his id, email, firstName and lastName.

  - I send theses informations back to the client. He's able to modify his firstName and lastName if he wants. Then send it back to the API.
  - The API register the User.

---

They both works like a charm, but i'm facing some problems:

1. When registering with facebook, if the user id is already in the database, i consider that the user has already subscribed to my service. But how can i identify him using basic auth afterwards ?

The first question brought me to the others. I've read everywhere that Basic Auth isn't secure enough. So i was thinking about, first of all, buy a SSL certificate, then change my authentification system to OAuth 2.0.

I was thinking that if i do that, i would be able to send a token back to my user that logged in with Facebook, which would answer my first question.

2. But is OAuth2.0 the solution here ?
3. Am i doing things right with my Facebook registration ?
4. How does that callback stuff works when i want to login using my own users on my Ionic app ?

There's so many things that seems unclear about OAuth2.0 that i don't want to start implementing it and then figure out than it wasn't the right solution for my problem. I've always thought that OAuth2.0 was the right system to choose if you want other services to use your service. I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So first thing first. HTTP Basic is perfectly secure if you are doing it over SSL.

OAuth 2.0 is an authorisation method.

OAuth is used when you want to make API calls on behalf of a user registered on other service. The other service has to provide the OAuth functionality for it to be usable by you. Let's say, you don't want to have a Registration function in your app but want to register users via Facebook, etc, you'll give an option to sign in using Facebook. So what happens is you are asking the user to give you access to access some of their Facebook account's info (more or less). You can read about it here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

On the other hand, you can be the provider so that other services can use your service.

Many services let you create a local account and also give you an option to signup with other services like Facebook, Google etc..... The handle the cases on their backend side.

Let's say you want to give option of Sign in with Facebook, you'll have to take care of a couple of cases:

1. **Associating Facebook Login with an already logged-in account** - This is the case where someone uses an app's custom login system to create an account. Later, while they are still logged in they want to associate their Facebook account with it. For example, people can sign up to Spotify with an email address and a password, but they can later choose to associate that account with their Facebook account using Facebook Login, such as when they want to publish their listening activity to their timeline.

   For this, you want to add a Facebook log in flow, like Spotify does.

   One thing you have to take care is the merging of your local account and the Facebook flow account info. It is advised that you create separate tables for this as this will ease the process when you want to add more providers like Google, etc.
2. **Merging separately created accounts with Facebook Login** - In this situation, a person logged in to your app with their own credentials such as an email and password for example. Later, when the person logs out they choose to sign in to your app using Facebook Login. Your app will now have two accounts for the same person, one created via the app login system, the other created via the Facebook Login flow. In order to provide the best experience for that person, your app should attempt to merge these accounts into one.

   For this you have to request for email (assuming your app requires email for registration) from Facebook. If it's the same as the email registered in your app, you can merge these accounts. If it's not the same, then you should give an option to connect existing email/account.

You should go through the following for more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers